# $(this) returning undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why is $(this) returning undefined instead of the clicked element?

I've replaced $(this) with event.target and it works fine but would like to understand the issue with $(this), thank you!

```
$('.nav-search-options').on('click', (event) => {

  console.log($(this))

})
```

Comment: Fat arrow function (`=>`) does not bind `this`, that's why you must use `event.target` or use normal function

Comment: is this element .nav-search-options dynamically added by JS ?

Comment: @JayvirsinhVaghela "*I've replaced $(this) with event.target and **it works fine**"* - so clearly not a delegated event issue.

Comment: Brilliant thanks, just need to use a standard function, it is interesting how an arrow function doesn't bind this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@JamesJavascript.
It is partially right what Justinas said in the comment about arrow function - although there are more things to add.

Arrow functions do not have their own "this", instead they bind one from their parent scope.

To see what I mean, try this and see that it returns you the window object:

```
const myFunction = () => {
  console.log(this);
};

// call it
myFunction();
```

Read more about it here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions